# how can i make google like intelligence searching system?

Tags: asp.net

I want to make google like intelligence searching system for searching data from list in my project. i mean when i write something in google bar for searching it automatically start showing some related words in down side. how can i achieve that search in my project? should i use some API ?

Comment: Do you mean the auto-complete feature in Google search?

Answer (score 1):

With ASP.NET AJAX, you can use [`AutoComplete`](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx) control which would give you that functionality 'as is' without writing any extra code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Jquery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete) too